# How to add annotation at latitude and longitude point?

Tags: python, plotly

I draw markers on the map at latitude and longitude points.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
  lat=lat_list, 
  lon=lon_list, 
  mode='text+markers', 
  textposition='bottom  right')
)
```

[image]

I would also like to add `bgcolor` as in the picture, but this parameter is in the `add_annotation ()` function.

**And here is my question:**

How to add markers using `add_annotation()` using latitude and longitude values, since this function does not have `lat` , `lon` parameters.
Is there any way to convert latitude and longitude to `x` and `y` ?